# iMessage sign-in not working correctly after changing Apple ID

Tags: ios, messages, apple-id

I wanted to sign up for Apple iMessage with a different email, so I created a new Apple ID and every time I try to sign in with that one, it asks me for the password again and again. This loop continues until it finally says that my Apple ID password is incorrect, but I know it is not.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where are you trying to sign in? System Preferences or in Messages.app?